# Jade template engine - Each Iteration Offset

Tags: node.js, foreach, express, template-engine, pug

Is there a way to offset the 'each' iteration when using the Jade template engine?

for example, when passing in the object named list:

```
ul
   each item in list
      li #{item}
```

Will output

```
<ul>
   <li> Item 1 </li>
   <li> item 2 </li>
   <li> item 3.....
...
</ul>
```

But I want the first item to be displayed differently than the rest of the items, like so:

```
<ul>
   <li> Item 1: First Item in list! </li>
   <li> item 2 </li>
   <li> item 3.....
...
</ul>
```

So does anyone know a way to offset the 'each' statement in Jade so that I can render the first item separately and then render each following item starting at the 2nd index?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
each item, i in list
  li= item
  if i === 1
    | : First item in list!
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using if - else to display the first item differently (i'm using partials, not the exact example i gave). Also, I had to make i === 0 to get the first item. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Jackie See my answer for current solution and examples.

Answer (score 2):

If @Johnathan's answer does not work for you:
In Jade 1.7 the following works:

```
for item, i in list
    li= item
    if i === 0
        | : First item in list!
```

http://www.learnjade.com/tour/iteration/

Also note the 0 index vs 1 index.